# RoR: PSQL to ruby - .join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, join, psql

I realize this is a bit of an elementary level question, but I am at a wall that I can't seem to get past. I had a friend of mine help me out with writing this Postgres code, and now I am trying to convert it into ruby, and I'm honestly not sure how to. I can't seem to find any documentation on how to properly order all of the pieces of the request.

Postgres:

```
SELECT
        assets.id,
        count(assets_users.asset_id) as the_count
FROM assets
LEFT OUTER JOIN assets_users ON assets.id = assets_users.asset_id
WHERE asset_profile_id = 7
GROUP BY assets.id
HAVING count(*) > 0
ORDER BY the_count;
```

Ruby:

```
def order_assets
  @order = Asset.select("assets.id").count("assets_users.asset_id").joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN assets_users ON assets.id = assets_users.asset_id").group("assets.id").having("count(*) > 0").order("assets_users.asset_id")
end
```

EDIT:

New Ruby code:

```
def order_assets
  @order = Asset.select("assets.id, count('assets_users.asset_id) as the_count")
                .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN assets_users ON assets.id = assets_users.asset_id")
                .group("assets.id")
                .having("count(*) > 0").order("the_count")
end
```

I want all of the yellow'd assets to be on the top, when the ones with users filled in below.

[image: Screenshot of Problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the equivalent code :-

```
@order = Asset.select("assets.id, count(assets_users.asset_id) as the_count")
              .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN assets_users ON assets.id = assets_users.asset_id")
              .where("asset_profile_id = ?", current_asset_profile_id)
              .group("assets.id")
              .having("count(*) > 0")
              .order("the_count")
```

Comment: How would I get it to do all of this, but where the `asset_profile_id` is the current one, rather than specifying?

Comment: Didn't get you.. Can you be more specific ?

Comment: So, rather than `.where(asset_profile_id: 7)`, how to set the where to the current `asset_profile_id` that I'm on. Like, `.where(asset_profile_id: current_asset_profile_id)`. Do I just have to remove the `.where`?

Comment: This code doesn't seem to have the same effect of the Postgres code. Any idea why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64644/discussion-between-arup-rakshit-and-briknthewall).